# can't see rect on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, drawing, drawing2d

I am trying to draw a rect to the screen but it doesn't show up here is the code used

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="drawer.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

main.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var render = canvas.getContext("2d")

fillColor(255,0,125)
rectangle(25,25.50,100)
```

drawer.js

```
function rectangle(x, y, w, h){
    render.beginPath()
    render.rect(x, y, w, h)
    render.fill()
    render.stroke()
}
function fillColor(r, g, b){
    r=String(r)
    g=String(g)
    b=String(b)
    render.fillStyle = "rgb"+r+","+g+"n"+b+")"
}
```

I have tried on chrome and opera gx but the rect won't show up

Comment: Why did you separate it in two different `.js` files?

Comment: that is what a tutorial i was following did, but the rect showed up for the person making the tutorial and not for me